# Execution of docker file fails via jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

When i run below command on cmd, it runs well with below output:

```
$ docker run --env-file /home/sonarqube/pr-config.env -d --add-host="host1:192.168.0.18" 243c286dec63 94ab7264a038dc6a91f5e457e19fba8effa48d82153fe945d06cd64aec4f369f

$ docker logs 94ab7264a038dc6a91f5e457e19fba8effa48d82153fe945d06cd64aec4f369f
```

> ============= test session starts ============
>
> platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
>   rootdir: /code, inifile: collected 6 items
>
> predictor/tests/test_server.py ......
>   [100%]
>   ========== 6 passed in 1.31 seconds ==========

But when i run the same command via jenkins pipeline, it fails with below error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='host1',
>   port=8088): Max retries exceeded with url: //predict/api/v1 (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name
>   or service not known',))
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:516:
>   ConnectionError

Jenkins file is as below:

```
    def awesomeVersion = 'UNKNOWN'
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('SCM Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master', url: 'git@github.com:xyx.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Docker build'){
            steps{
                script {
          awesomeVersion = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'hostname --ip-address')
        }
            sh "docker run --env-file /home/sonarqube/pr-config.env -d --add-host='host1:${awesomeVersion}' 243c286dec63"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why it might fail ?

Comment: The resolution was to pass public ip but causes another problem for which i have to read on how to make two containers to communicate via compose

Answer (score 0):

One can use this new jenkins file to resolve the problem

```
    def awesomeVersion = 'UNKNOWN'
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('SCM Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master', url: 'git@github.com:rahul-padhee/Sigmoid.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Docker build'){
            steps{
                script {
          awesomeVersion = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'curl --silent http://169.254.xxx.xxx/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4')
        }
            sh "docker run --env-file /home/sonarqube/pr-config.env -d --add-host='host1:${awesomeVersion}' 243c286dec63"
            }
        }
    }
}
```